# SSRS URLs having issues

Tags: reporting-services

**A little background info...**

By far and large the URLs worked perfectly fine. Occasionally either my machine, or the server itself couldn't access the Web Service URL or the Report Manager URL. For the server a restart fixed this, for me I had to reset my winsock which never worked and ended up System Restoring to a working date.

When I say couldn't access I mean getting the "This Page Cannot Be Displayed" message, or the "Please turn on TLS 1.0 etc etc" message.

The last few days the issue is now widespread. Everyone was having issues gettings to the URLs even the server. I figured it may have been some windows updates causing issues so I removed all the updates around the timeframe in which it started and tested and got nothing.

Came back the next day (today) and same issue except the only way to access it is through a hyperlink thats clicked or copy/pasted.

**The issue:**

If you manually type the URL it will not work. You have to copy and paste the hyperlink from a working page. I used a link to a rendered report and deleted back to /ReportServer and it pulls up the directory. I've never seen something like this happen before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The Solution:**

Apparently you have to type in www. as well

I was so use to skipping that for most pages.

https://analytics.domain.com/ReportServer = fail

https://www.analytics.domain.com/ReportServer = win